# What is the recommended way to setup projects like this?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

We are working on a large project. The project has multiple external sites and multiple internal sites all stored in Subversion.

The external sites allow a customer to make requests of various things we provide, pay utility bills and more. We decided to break many of these functions apart because most work completely different than the others. So this is one Visual Studio solution with the WebUI and the database layer broken into two projects each. For instance, utility billing has a Utility.WebUI project and a Utility.Domain project. All DB/business logic is kept in the domain project.

The internal sites bridge the gap between the back-office system (IBM i) and the web database. Also will replace/enhance some of our older RPG programs. In theory they should use the exact same database logic that the external sites use because they access the same database right? What is the best way to reference these projects from a different solution? Should I just add a reference to the dll or should I import that project from the external application solution into the internal application solution?

This comes down to that we have two developers working on this project. Myself, I do most of the back-end coding. The other developer does most of the GUI coding. So we need to make sure that this project works on multiple workstations.

Does this make sense? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) property to reference the shared project into your project(s).

You have to choose between 1) referencing the directory containing the shared project's source code (i.e. where the csproj and cs files are located) or 2) referencing the directory containing the shared project's build output (assembly / dll).

I normally prefer method 1) since it makes modifications to the shared project's source code easier (you can make changes without having to open the shared project's solution in a second instance of Visual Studio). If you don't intend to make changes to the shared project often then method 2) might be better. It reduces compile time and prevents accidental modifications of the shared project's source code. Both methods are fine - matter of taste.

It is recommended for both methods that you version your shared project. i.e. create tags with version numbers and reference the tags, not the trunk. When a new version of the shared project comes out you can update the svn:externals property of your other project(s) with the new version number, run "svn update" to download the new version of the shared project, and recompile. This works especially well if you have a build server for the shared project that does the tagging for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a sort of "commons" solution that contains the common projects and then refer to these projects in you main solutions using SVN external pointing to the project folder in the SVN trunk.

Commons SVN repository must follow the suggested repository structure (trunk, branches, tags) to have always stable commons projects.

In this scenario you can consider to use a dependency management tool, such as NPanday or NDepend, where you must declare to which version of which assemblies every project depends on;  using these tools you can have a local repository (such as Artifactory or Nexus) of binary assemblies to refer to, or choose to use SVN externals to refer directly to source code.